# getview method is not calling in custom listview method in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having an `Arraylist` as [x,y,z..]. I want this `ArrayList` [x,y,z..] in `ListView` but `getview()` method is not getting invoked
 I am trying this code :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
public static ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();

public Context Context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr) 
{
    Context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    arr=arr;

}
public int getCount() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arr.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arr.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
    System.out.println(arr.get(posstion));
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selecteditemlistview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.textViewSelectedText = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectedtext);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textViewSelectedText.setText(arr.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textViewSelectedText = null;
    }
}
```

`System.out.println(arr.get(posstion));`

This line is inside `getview()` method and it is not printing the values.. please help me.

Comment: u r code is perfect ...pls check array size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the setAdapter function on the ListView to let it use your custom adapter

EDIT: There is a typo in the CustomAdapter constructor: the code should read

```
this.arr = arr
```

instead of

```
arr = arr
```

Comment: i can set setContentView(R.layout.selecteditem);
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selecteditemlist);
     adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arr);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Ok, got it! In the CustomAdapter constructor, use this.arr=arr; instead of arr=arr;

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly spelled the position
change

```
System.out.println(arr.get(posstion));
```

by

```
System.out.println(arr.get(position));
```

Comment: i give like this only...System.out.println(arr.get(posstion));

Comment: which possition you are accesing here I cannot see possition variable anywhere else in your code

Comment: post your exception in logcat here

Comment: Your code is fine except that `posstion` I don't know why are you using this `arr.get(posstion)`

Answer (score 0):

inside ur getview method your sop is  System.out.println(arr.get(posstion));. i think it should be  System.out.println(arr.get(position));
because in your getview method int position is defined and not posstion. check the spelling in your code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   System.out.println(arr.get(position));
}
```

even if this doesnt work try giving sop in

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arr) 
{     
   Context=context;  
   inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);  
   arr=arr;  
   System.out.println("arr: " + arr.size);

}
```

if size is 0 then u r not getting any result from activity classto this adapter

Comment: System.out.println("arr: " + arr.size); i can able to print array size value..but only getview method is not calling ..

Comment: ur adapter code seems to be correct.. ru getting any exception? what is appearing on emulator screen when u run the app?